# Show that a linear transformation and its associated matrix representation have the same minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

I am given the following question:

Consider the complex vector space of $2\times 2$ square matrices $V=M_2(\mathbb{C})$ Given $A \in M_2(\mathbb{C})$, we have a linear transformation $M_A:V\rightarrow V$ defined by $M_A(B) =AB$.
Show that A and $M_A$ have the same minimal polynomial.

Now, I am not sure what the actual difference between A and $M_A$ are. To me, this seems tautological as they are both essentially the same thing. What conceptually am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p(z)=a_0+\dots+z^n$ be the minimal polynomial of $M_A$. Then we know that $p(M_A)v=0$ for all $v\in M_2(\Bbb{C})$.

Because the minimal polynomial is unique, all you have to show is that $p(A)=0$.

Hint: Take $B=I$.